# $.getJSON doesn't call neither 'done()' nor 'fail()'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple call:

```
$.getJSON(serviceAddress)
    .done(function(result, status) {
        bo.BusinessObject.DtosToaKoArray(result, resultList);
    })
    .fail(function(result, status) {
        logger.logError(result);
    })
    .success(function (result, status) {
        bo.BusinessObject.DtosToaKoArray(result, resultList);
    })
    .error(function (result, status) {
        logger.logError(result);
    });
```

But none of the callback functions doesn't call. Using firebug I checked that the `HttpRequest` was successful and returned some Json.

I also tried to use `$.ajax` but it doesn't help too.

It seems all of callbacks aren't working!

Comment: So no errors in the JavaScript console? Why are you using both `.fail()` and `.error()`, and both `.done()` and `.success()`?

Comment: "and returned some Json" --- is it the same domain or another?

Comment: All due respect, this is almost certainly observation error. One of the callback *is* getting called, but then the function it's calling (`bo.BusinessObject.whatever`) isn't working correctly.

Comment: @zerkms: Even if it were cross-domain, `fail` and `error` would be called: http://jsbin.com/isuzer/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/isuzer/1/edit))

Comment: add a console log to the success callback. Frankly, do

Comment: @nnnnnn I put them just to check if they works.

Comment: @zerkms It's from another domain. I had that problem former. But as I used CORS it's resolved. Before using CORS the fail method was called having no result. but now there's the Json result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(I think this is actually an answer. :-) )*

All due respect, this is almost certainly observation error. One of the callbacks *is* getting called, but then the function it's calling (`bo.BusinessObject.whatever`) isn't working correctly.

You can diagnose that by:

1. Putting breakpoints on the first statement in each callback in the debugger (all modern browsers have a built-in debugger),
2. ...or if you prefer by putting a line at the beginning of each callback, e.g.:

   ```
   .done(function() {
       console.log("Done");
       // ...
   })
   ```

Comment: I have breakpoints on starting of done() and fail() functions. After that I put the question this here!

Comment: @mehrandvd: Put a breakpoint on the `$.getJSON` statement as well and see if it gets hit. Perhaps you have *another* `$.getJSON` elsewhere which is the one actually getting triggered. Bottom line: jQuery ***will*** call one of those callbacks.

Comment: Putting `console.log` helped. As matter of fact, it seems that breakpoints on empty functions doesn't work!

Comment: @mehrandvd: In that situation, you can use the `debugger;` statement, which prevents the function being empty and defines a breakpoint. :-)